# Actionscript3 Main class is the root, but does not allow the Animate Virtual Camera

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, jquery-animate, virtual

I've recently started learning Animate CC with Actionscript 3.

I'm trying to use Animate's "Virtual Camera" feature, giving me a camera that can pan, rotate, and zoom the game.

It's easy to implement a Camera when the root has no subclass. For example, you can put a block on screen, and add a camera effect within the timeline itself, and play your movie it. Easy.

But when I give the fla a class ("Main") and give that class an external AS3 file, I get an error:

[Specific image showcasing what I mean about giving FLA a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3bVA.png)

The code below is "Main.as"

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import fl.VirtualCamera;

public class Main extends MovieClip {


    var camera;

    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        camera = VirtualCamera.getCamera(root);
        trace(camera);
    }

}

}
```

Now, even when I had *absolutely no code* (other than functional necessities) in Main.as, and a Camera in the timeline, I would get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property ___layerDepthEnabled___ not found on Main and there is no default value.
at privatePkg::___Camera___/cameraControl()
```

I added in this code above to Main, and I get the same error.

The only thing that fixes it is changing

```
camera = VirtualCamera.getCamera(root);
```

to:

```
camera = VirtualCamera.getCamera(this.parent);
```

and that, while eliminating the code, also doesn't actually give me a camera to use.

**How can I use a Virtual Camera and still have Main.as?**

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I just tried it in CC2017 and it worked fine with no code in document class.

Comment: Try declaring **public dynamic class Main** because it is not impossible that **VirtualCamera** class is expecting a generic **MovieClip** as root (which is dynamic = you can add any property without raising an exception).

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis: I know. I didn't ask if it would work with no code in the document class. How does it work *with* a document class?

Comment: @Organis: I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: @AndyMalik - I was addressing your statement:  "Now, even when I had absolutely no code (other than functional necessities) in Main.as, and a Camera in the timeline, I would get this error"...     To clarify, I tried it **with** a document class with a couple of functions that don't relate to the Camera.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis - Ah, my bad. I didn't realize that's what you were talking about. The "Functional Necessities" for my Main.as was simply Importing MovieClip and extending Main from a MovieClip. If I didn't have that, then I would get an error about not subclassing Main to a Moive Clip. Is that the functional necessities you did as well?

Comment: @Organis: Dynamic did work. It was something else causing the issue. If you post your answer as an Answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring **public dynamic class Main** because it is not impossible that **VirtualCamera** class is expecting a generic **MovieClip** as root (which is dynamic = you can add any property without raising an exception).