# Adobe Animate 2019 BUG? Air Mobile development layerDepthEnabled Error #1056:

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Anyone know why I am getting this strange error? Here is the code I used. I also make a little video for you to see what it's doing as well.  Check out the link below.

https://youtu.be/xPx2A13lIJA

Here is the full error code:

```
[SWF] love.swf - 3194 bytes after decompression
ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property ___layerDepthEnabled___ on love.
    at love/frame1()[love::frame1:10]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
```

Comment: PS: Possibly related to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48673142/2057709)? Did you involve any camera options in your code or project settings?

Comment: No. It seems to be enabled by default and you can not remove it.

Comment: That's too bad for you Animate users. I cannot reproduce error with my CS-based IDE. Does this entry from [the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/animate/using/working-with-camera-in-animate-cc.html#Enablingordisablingthecamera) help to solve the issue? Did the answer from top comment's link help your project compile without error?

Comment: You should probably report it as a bug right away instead of posting here. But, seeing that you pretty much don't do a single thing except creating a project and an empty class, it should be a bug somewhere, maybe in the framework and not in IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, they have a setting called "Advanced Layers Mode" that's turned on by default that's triggering the error messages. You have to disable it.

**Disable Advanced Layers Mode in Properties**

In the Properties Window:
Properties Window > Advanced Settings > Mode > Uncheck Advanced Layers and click on Make Default

Comment: You... are AMAZING. One thousand Thanks! :)